# Confusing behaviour in vue $set

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

What i am trying to archieve with mountState is to mount the page state before making the get request to the server based on data contained in 'filters'. Everytime something changes a new url if generated by history.pushState.

When the method is called the first time by de if condition (in case someone is acessing it by the URL directrly), it sucessfully updates the state and makes the correct get request. But when it is based in the popstate event, mountState fails to update the properties. The weirdest part is that if i inspect the console.log(this.filters) it seems that the data was updated, but this isn't reflected by what is displayed in vue devtools. I know vue router could be used to solve this kind of problem, but since this would be used only in a very small part of the website i was trying to archieve it buy manually reading the history.location.href. Any light in this problem?

```
    data() {
        return {
            filters: {
                ordertype: null,
                ordermethod: null,
                pricemin: null,
                pricemax: null,
                kmmin: null,
                kmmax: null,
                yearmin: null,
                yearmax: null,
            }
        }
    },

    mounted() {

        let mountState = () => {
            let paramsArray = [];
            let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href);

            for (let param of params) {
                paramsArray.push(param);
            }
            console.log(paramsArray);

            //for some reason URLSearchParams return values before '?', this is shifted from array
            paramsArray.shift();

            for (let test of paramsArray) {
                this.$set(this.filters, test[0], test[1]);
            }

            console.log(this.filters);
        }


        addEventListener('popstate', event => {
            console.log(window.location.href);
            mountState();
        })


        if (window.location.href.includes('&')) {
            mountState();
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't need to use `vue $set`

If you want to mount a particular state, you can use the mounted method

If you want to listen to the URL change you can watch the router

```js
watch: {
  '$route' (value) {
    // you have access the query params with this.$route.params
  }
}
```

Try this and let me know